# Referencing a field value in a Phoenix form

Tags: templates, elixir, phoenix-framework

In a Phoenix .eex/.leex form created with `<%= f = form_for @changeset…`, is there a way to reference one of the field values in a CSS class definition?

For example, I’d like to hide a div element if field1's value is “”. This is the code that I drafted that doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class= <%= if :field1 == "" do %>
                 "hidden"
            <% else %>
                 " "
             <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Ecto.Changeset.get_field/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_field/3), [`Ecto.Changeset.get_change/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_change/3) or just go for `@changeset.data.field1`.

Check the docs for the differences between those three and put a temporary `<%= inspect @changeset %>` inside your form to see what `data` and `changes` are all about.

So one way of doing what you want is:

```
<div class="<%= if @changeset.data.value1 == "", do: "hidden", else: "" %>">
```

(Notice that I've put the `<%= ... %>` tags inside the double qoutes.)